# Can I sue a restaurant for serving me meat in a vegetarian dish and not apologizing or doing anything about their mistake when pointed out?

Tags: restaurants

I went to a Korean restaurant for the first time with some friends. Knowing there aren’t many vegetarian options, and also being unfamiliar with Korean food, I made sure to check the menu carefully and double check with the restaurant staff to make sure the dish I picked for myself was vegetarian. I was assured multiple times by the restaurant staff that the dish I ordered was vegetarian. After receiving my food, one of my friends tried it and pointed out to me that there was beef in my food, and two of my friends confirmed (after trying it). We asked the waiter again if my dish was vegetarian and they said “it should be.” So we pointed out the meat in the dish to one of the waiters who was very confident that it was beef. When we told her it was supposed to be a vegetarian meal, she became flustered and went to check with the other waiter who then also came to our table and confirmed it was beef. He dryly said sorry and we asked if they could do anything about it since I can’t have meat for religious reasons. He said there was nothing they could do about it. We asked if they could at least take off my dish from the bill or make me another one, and he refused. In this situation, am I allowed to sue this restaurant?

Comment: you don't have to pay for thigs that are materially different from what you ordered.  Are you saying you ordered vegetarian, they gave you non-vegetarian, but made you pay for it anyway?